# how to contronl drawer and endDrawer with 2 button in flutter

Tags: button, flutter, dart, navigation-drawer, drawer

I want to program 2 buttons: the first opens the `Drawer` and the second opens the `endDrawer`.

the first button I used

```
onTap: () => _drawerKey.currentState.openEndDrawer(),
```

the second I used

```
onTap: () => _drawerKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
```

but the code didn't work

Comment: try this **Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();**

Comment: dear @Florian,I have a flutter app with drawer and end drawer, in the app there is 2 button, the first button open the drawer, and the other open the endDrawer,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this what I was need

```
        Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code,

```
class Act_Drawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Act_DrawerState createState() => _Act_DrawerState();
}

class _Act_DrawerState extends State<Act_Drawer> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = new GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldkey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Drawer Demo"),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, setState) {
            return IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.format_align_left),
              onPressed: () {
                _scaffoldkey.currentState.openDrawer();
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, setState) {
            return IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.format_align_right),
              onPressed: () {
                _scaffoldkey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
              },
            );
          },
          )
        ],
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(),
      endDrawer: Drawer(),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the code work with the appBar, but I'm using two buttons,
GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                    _scaffoldkey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
                    },
                    child: DrawerButtonMenu(),
                ),
 GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _scaffoldkey.currentState.openDrawer();
              },child: DollarButton(),
            ),

Comment: I tried the code in empty app it dose work, but in my app I've got error 
════════ (2) Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The method 'openDrawer' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: openDrawer()

Answer (score 1):

**The method 'openDrawer' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: openDrawer()**
If you get this error: it is because you have not declared the global key inside your second (nested scaffold).

```
 final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();// this is declared inside your State
```

Below is a working example

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Scaffold(
    primary: true,
    appBar: actionBar(),
    drawer: MainNavigationDrawer(),
    body: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,// VERY IMPORTANT YOU CALL THIS otherwise you will get the error above
        endDrawer: MainNavigationDrawer(),
        body: singleScrollView()),
   ),
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Global key of scaffold and put it in your scaffold......

```
class _AppState extends State<MyHome> {

    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size(null, 180),
            child: _getAppBar(
                _selectedDrawerIndex), //CustomAppBar(_scaffoldKey, controller),
          ),
          drawer: createDrwaer(),
          body: WillPopScope(
            child: _getDrawerFragment(_selectedDrawerIndex),
            onWillPop: () {
              if (_selectedDrawerIndex == 1) {
                _onSelectItem(0);
              } else {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              }
            },
          ) //_getDrawerFragment(_selectedDrawerIndex),
          );
    }
  }
```

after that use this on tap of button...

```
onTap: () =>_scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
```

Be sure to make your class Stateful

Comment: I already made the global key
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _drawerKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
and remember that I have two button with tow drawers (Drawer and endDrawer)
I can open the drawer but the endDrawer didn't open with the button

Comment: So please post your full code or you can try this _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer()

Comment: I got this error
"The method 'openDrawer' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: openDrawer()"

Comment: there is a possibility that you have not initialized global key or something else I will solve this but first, you have to post your full code.

Comment: sorry I can't show the full code because of company rules but, here is the error
════════ (2) Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The method 'openDrawer' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: openDrawer()